# I want to add two extremely large numbers in python which even bignum can't handle

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new in python,I want to add two extremely large numbers in python which even bignum can't handle. I can take these two numbers as a string and then can calculate from the end and as like we used to do in  old school addition process. we can take the carriage and add it to the next numbers and so on. 
Please assist.

Comment: We're not doing _all_ your homework for you. What do you have so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Can you show us how bignum cannot handle that?

Comment: Hi Ayhan. Yes, bignum can handle the same but just in case the number is extremely large, than we can only accept it as a string and needs to perform the action. :) @ayhan

Comment: For the record, Python 3's integers are of arbitrary precision. You don't need to implement this yourself, unless it's homework.

Comment: that was a homework actually. :)) @AKX

Answer (score 7):

The question seemed interesting enough for a Christmas Day coding snack.

Here's my implementation using many of the builtins in Python.

- `reversed` is used to iterate over the digit sequences from right to left, i.e. like we would when computing on paper
- `zip_longest` "fills" in the sequences' ends with zeroes (as we would ignore digits on paper)
- `divmod` computes the carried-forward value and the current digit in a single call.
- The result is reversed, so it's once more reversed to be least-significant-digit-last, and stray zeroes on the left are removed using `lstrip`.

It does not handle negative numbers, though.

---

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def add(a, b):
    out = []
    a = [int(c) for c in str(a)]
    b = [int(c) for c in str(b)]
    carry = 0
    for ca, cb in zip_longest(reversed(a), reversed(b), fillvalue=0):
        carry, digit = divmod(ca + cb + carry, 10)
        out.append(str(digit))
    return "".join(reversed(out)).lstrip("0")


a = 9999 ** 29
b = 3725241 ** 9

assert add(a, b) == str(a + b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved that after 3 hours of work. :)

```
def add_func(num1,num2):

    res_list = []

    number1 = str(num1)
    number2 = str(num2)
    length1 = len(str(number1))
    length2 = len(str(number2))


    if(length1 > length2):
        while(length1 > length2):
            number2 = '0' + number2
            length2 += 1

    if(length2 > length1):
        while(length2 > length1):
            number1 = '0' + number1
            length1 += 1

    i = max(length1,length2)

    carry = 0

    while(i > 0):
        if(int(number1[i-1]) + int(number2[i-1]) + carry > 9):
            result = str(int(number1[i-1]) + int(number2[i-1]) + carry)
            res_list.insert(0,(result[-1]))
            carry = 1

            if(i==1):
                result = str(int(number1[i-1]) + int(number2[i-1]) + carry)
                res_list[0]= result


        elif(int(number1[i-1]) + int(number2[i-1]) > 9):
            result = str(int(number1[i-1]) + int(number2[i-1]))
            res_list.insert(0,(result[-1]))
            carry = 1

        else:
            result = str(int(number1[i-1]) + int(number2[i-1]) + carry)
            res_list.insert(0,(result[-1]))
            carry = 0

        i -=1

    final_output = ('').join(res_list)
    return final_output

print(add_func(9999**29,3725241**9))
```

Comment: I still don't understand why you think Python doesn't handle this. I get the same result by simply executing `9999**29+3725241**9`.

Comment: You should post to codereview.stackexchange.com instead.  One thing you could do instead of duplicating code for filling in '0' is demand that length2>=length1 and swap the variables if this isn't true:  `if length2 < length1:  number2,number1 = number1,number2`.

Comment: Those numbers were just for testing out the functionality of the code. :) @ayhan

Comment: Do you have numbers that fail in pure Python but works with your function?